# redirection of https urls inside spring framework using spring security xml configuration

Tags: spring, spring-security, redirect

I have a Java EE setup with Apache in front end , jboss eap in backend. Have load balancer before apache layer.

I need to route all https requests hitting load balancer via apache to jboss. I use proxy pass for doing that in the apache connector layer. Have changed server.xml in jboss eap.

In login module we found that after logging in the page is getting redirected to url properly but :80 gets added to the IP address (https mode).

```
     For example: When i click login url is https://1.1.1.1/tt/login.glx, after successful login it gets redirected to https://1.1.1.1:80/tt/view.glx
```

Not sure what is missing ?

Any ideas ?

We are using spring container and it does the redirection to another page using below setting in the context xml file.

```
     <form-login login-page="/login.glx" default-target-url="/view.glx" always-use-default-target='false' authentication-failure-url="/failed.glx"/>
```

Comment: Which port number is used for HTTPS in JBoss? I have the similar issue when Tomcat was configured to use 8080 (or 80) for HTTPS.